# MySQL query returns data (u'example',)

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using a mysql lib on python, and when I try to do this query:

```
SELECT product FROM database1.contacts WHERE contact="%s" % (contact)
```

I get this:

```
(u'example',)
```

But I expect this:

```
example
```

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector

db_user = "root"
db_passwd = ""
db_host = "localhost"
db_name = "database1"

connector = mysql.connector.connect(user=db_user, password=db_passwd, host=db_host, database=db_name,
                                            buffered=True)
cursor = connector.cursor()
contact = "943832628"
get_product_sql = 'SELECT product FROM database1.contacts WHERE contact="%s"' % (contact)

cursor.execute(get_product_sql)

for product in cursor:
        print product
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are printing the whole row; print just the first column:

```
for product in cursor:
    print product[0]
```

or use tuple unpacking in the loop:

```
for product, in cursor:
    print product
```

Comment: Please explain why the expected is not the observer, leading to the need for applying your solution - I presume because mysql returns a tuple in python...but why are tuples requiring such `u` prefix?

Comment: @Elysiumplain: tuples do not require a `u` prefix; the question asker was using Python 2, and the value in the row is a [Unicode string](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). In Python 3, you'd just see `('example',)`.