# mysql query returns the data in the unicode format

Tags: python, mysql

I'm very new to Python and MySQL,  I have dumped a file  in database using python, on executing a query `Select * from table_name`
I am getting the result in Unicode format i.e

```
(1, u'John',u'smith')
(2, u'Markus',u'Doe')
(3, u'Andrew',u'smith')
```

but, I required in this format

```
(1, 'John','smith')
(2, 'Markus','Doe')
(3, 'Andrew','smith')
```

The file using encoding="utf-8" format
Because of this unicode format, I'm unable to perform any insertion based on foreign keys

python code for this problem:

```
with codecs.open("input.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
   for num,line in enumerate(f,1):
        try:

            words=line.split('\t')
            list =[]
            for word in words:
                list.append(word.encode("utf-8"))

            args = (list[0],list[0])
            cursor.execute(query,args)
f.close()
cursor.execute("Select * from table_name")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

print('Total Row(s):', cursor.rowcount)
for row in rows:
     print [type(word) for word in row]



conn.commit()         
conn.close()
```

Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154998/python-encoding-mysql

Comment: we have already tried the above link but not solving my problem

Comment: I don't know your python code. Possible to share it ? Meanwhile look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121829/mysql-query-returns-data-uexample

Comment: I have uploaed the code and Meanwhile on inserting data to another table, I'm facing mismatch on foreign keys